# A mp3 file is reeoncoded in a video software (shotcut), which bitrate (Audio Bitrate vs Lame Bitrate) do I need to use?

Tags: audio, audio-processing, mp3

I have downloaded a .mp3 file from the internet. "Right click" and "Properties" on Linux does not show up any bitrate (N/A) in the "Audio" tab.

Then, I executed following command in the terminal: `exiftool ambient.mp3`, which prints a lot of information into the terminal:

```
File Type Extension             : mp3
MIME Type                       : audio/mpeg
MPEG Audio Version              : 1
Audio Layer                     : 3
Audio Bitrate                   : 320 kbps
Sample Rate                     : 44100
Channel Mode                    : Stereo
MS Stereo                       : Off
Intensity Stereo                : Off
Copyright Flag                  : False
Original Media                  : True
Emphasis                        : None
Encoder                         : LAME3.99r
Lame VBR Quality                : 4
Lame Quality                    : 1
Lame Method                     : CBR
Lame Low Pass Filter            : 20.5 kHz
Lame Bitrate                    : 255 kbps
Lame Stereo Mode                : Stereo
Duration                        : 0:45:22 (approx)
```

Is the Lame Bitrate the correct one or the Audio Bitrate?

Extra: lame is on Ubuntu a mp3 lib called `libmp3lame`.

Comment: well, divide the length in seconds by the file size in bits by 2 (since it's stereo) and you get the bitrate of the audio stream (not accounting for single-digit percents of overhead). What, however "correct bitrate" is to you remains a mystery: you'll have to define that for us.

Comment: with the "correct bitrate" I mean the bitrate what it really is... I am trying to create a video... and for the audio settings, I need to set the bitrate... I read it out with the `exiftool`. then there are 2 terms using bitrate and I am confused of them.

Comment: but the bitrate of that audio file here has nothing to do with what you enter in that field; if you do *anything* but copy in the data stream into your video container, the thing will be re-encoded, anyway.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok. But I figured out the same sample rate is important... otherwise the music is not clear... 
I want to get sure and so I am using the same bitrate

Comment: no, that's not correct. Again, the bitrate of the original file has nothing to do with this, and both 320 kbps and 255 kbps are not "reasonable" bitrates for MP3, anyway. So, reencode using default settings.

Comment: mhm, I guess, I need to change the question... so that one of you can write a reasonable answer, right?